# Convert Json object array to list of property values in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have this list of objects -

`var o_list = [{id:1,name:jo},{id:2,name:mo}];`

and I want to extract something like this -

var list = [1,2]

Is there anything already built or how can we implement this.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @adeneo - Then should we use object in JSON format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just map it

```js
var o_list = [{id:1,name:"jo"},{id:2,name:"mo"}];

var list = o_list.map(x => x.id);

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(list, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Comment: It's working perfectly fine, as the snippet above shows. If it's not working for you, something else must be wrong.

Comment: Yes might be the case. Because in browser console its working but giving error in my project.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this using filters
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', '$filter',
  function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.values = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'asdas'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'blabla'
    }];
    
    // this is how you use filters in your script
    console.log($filter('extract')($scope.values));
  }
]);

myApp.filter('extract', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input.map(x => x.id);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ol ng-repeat="id in values | extract">
      <li ng-bind="id"></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate you can use underscore.js each method to get results

```
      var o_list = [{id:1,name:'jo'},{id:2,name:'mo'}];

        var list =[];
        _.each(o_list, function(d){
                         list.push(d.id)
                      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use only javscript `forEach` array method to get desired result

```
var o_list = [{id:1,name:'jo'},{id:2,name:'mo'}];

var list =[];
o_list.forEach(function(item){
list.push(item.id)

})

console.log(list)
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/w2wj159y/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var o_list = [{id:1,name:jo},{id:2,name:mo}];
var list = [];

for(i = 0; i < o_list.length; i++){
   list.push(o_list[i].id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple for loop

```
var o_list = [{id:1,name:'jo'},{id:2,name:'mo'}];
var s=[];
for (var i=0;i< o_list.length;i++){
 s.push(o_list[i].id);

}
```